# Union only if database exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple databases with the same tables. I have a table called Invoices. The way I am doing my query now is like:

```
Select * from [Db1].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
UNION ALL Select * from [Db2].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
UNION ALL Select * from [Db3].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
```

That query throws an error if Db3 does not exists for example. I was hopping to create something like

```
IF db_id('Db1') is not null  -- if database Db1 exists
    Select * from [Db1].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
IF db_id('Db2') is not null
    UNION ALL Select * from [Db2].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
IF db_id('Db3') is not null
    UNION ALL Select * from [Db3].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'someId'
```

That query does not work but hope I illustrate what am I trying to accomplish

### Edit

**Thanks a lot for the help! If the first database is not found my query will start with `UNION ALL` thus giving an error . How can I prevent that?**

Comment: See my answer it will generate the command for you dynamically. Thus based on the absence of the database or not. You dont need a list of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL for that

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

IF db_id('Db1') is not null  -- if database Db1 exists
    SET @sql = @sql + 'Select * from [Db1].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
IF db_id('Db2') is not null
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@sql) > 0
        SET @sql = @sql + N' UNION ALL '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'Select * from [Db2].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
END
IF db_id('Db3') is not null
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@sql) > 0
        SET @sql = @sql + N' UNION ALL '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'Select * from [Db3].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
END

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This is better than mine as it includes checks before unioning.

Comment: @Stuart and Szymon see my answer for a alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because SQL server parses the query before execution and is trying to validate the dbs/tables in your select script.  So the only way you can do this is to do it using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = ''

IF db_id('Db1') is not null  -- if database Db1 exists
    SET @sql+='Select * from [Db1].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
IF db_id('Db2') is not null
    SET @sql+='UNION ALL Select * from [Db2].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
IF db_id('Db3') is not null
    SET @sql+='UNION ALL Select * from [Db3].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''

EXEC (@sql)
```

Stu.

Answer (score 1):

You would need dynamic SQL here

```
declare @qry varchar(max)=''
IF db_id('Db1') is not null  -- if database Db1 exists
        set @qry='Select * from [Db1].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
IF db_id('Db2') is not null
    begin 
        set @qry=@qry + case when @qry<>'' then ' UNION ' ELSE '' end
        set @qry=@qry +' UNION ALL Select * from [Db2].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
    end

IF db_id('Db3') is not null
    begin 
        set @qry=@qry + case when @qry<>'' then ' UNION ' ELSE '' end
        set @qry=@qry +' UNION ALL Select * from [Db3].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''someId'''
    end

if @qry<>'' 
EXEC(@qry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest version here

This will print the statement you need. Just set your output to text and run the following command.

```
EXEC sp_MSForeachDB ' DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cmd = ''SELECT * FROM [?].dbo.Invoices WHERE ID=''''Something'''' UNION ALL''
PRINT @CMD
'
```

I am sure you can modify the code to execute rather than print. It is not perfect yet but your should be able to work with it.

Update ok so while short that version wont work easily. However you can get the same results by applying this technique.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tables
(
    TABLE_NAME SYSNAME NOT NULL
);

EXEC sp_MSForeachDB ' DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)
INSERT INTO #TABLES SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
SELECT * FROM #Tables
DROP TABLE #Tables
```

This will get the same results as the union and you never have to know all the databases ahead of time. Thus if you add DB2000 this will work as is. You will never have to edit the query again.